# [react native][ios][react-native-background-fetch] dont't work on ios

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, react-native-background-fetch

I've implemented **react-native-background-fetch** in my app, and it works well on Android, but not on ios - **Xcode Version 11.4**

Simulate Background Fetch works. I noticed also that Background Fetch triggers once on the first application start, but not anymore. On Android Background Fetch triggers every 15 min.

My configuration is:

react-native: 0.62.1

react-native-background-fetch: 2.8.0

Here is my code:

**App.js**

```
class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount () {
    ...
    newPostNotificationService.initNotifications()
    ...
```

**newPostsNotificationSevice.js**

```
initNotifications = async () => {
  this.configureNotifications() // Configures PushNotification

  BackgroundFetch.registerHeadlessTask(this.fetchNewPosts)

  BackgroundFetch.configure({
    minimumFetchInterval: 15,
    stopOnTerminate: false,
    startOnBoot: true,
    enableHeadless: true
  }, this.fetchNewPosts,
    (error) => {
      console.log(error, '[js] RNBackgroundFetch failed to start')
    })

  BackgroundFetch.status((status) => {
    switch (status) {
      case BackgroundFetch.STATUS_RESTRICTED:
        console.log('BackgroundFetch restricted')
        break
      case BackgroundFetch.STATUS_DENIED:
        console.log('BackgroundFetch denied')
        break
      case BackgroundFetch.STATUS_AVAILABLE:
        console.log('BackgroundFetch is enabled')
        break
    }
  })
}
```

**fetchNewPosts** Method in newPostsNotificationSevice.js

```
async fetchNewPosts(taskId) {
  console.log('BackgroundFetch Start', taskId)

  if (AppState.currentState === 'active') {
    BackgroundFetch.finish(taskId)
    return
  }

  dataStorageService.getSettings().then(async (settings) => {
    if (!settings.notifications) {
      BackgroundFetch.finish(taskId)
      return
    }

    const url = config.API_URL + config.API_ENDPOINTS.POSTS + '&per_page=1&page=1'

    let data
    if (!config.DATA_MOCK.NEW_POSTS) {
      data = await fetch(url)
        .then((response) => {
          return response.json()
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error)
        })
    } else {
      data = postsMock.posts
    }

    data = data.map(item => {
      return new PostShort(item)
    })

    data = data.filter(item => {
      return item.sendPush
    })

    if (data.length === 0) {
      BackgroundFetch.finish(taskId)
    }

    dataStorageService.getPostsIndex().then(postsIndex => {
      if (postsIndex.length > 0 && postsIndex.indexOf(data[0].id) !== -1) {
        BackgroundFetch.finish(taskId)
        return
      }

      dataStorageService.getNotificationsIndex().then(notificationsIndex => {
        if (notificationsIndex.indexOf(data[0].id) !== -1) {
          BackgroundFetch.finish(taskId)
          return
        }
        const notificationBody = entities.decode(data[0].title)
        const notificationNumber = notificationsIndex.length + 1
        console.log('notificationNumber', notificationNumber)

        PushNotification.localNotification({
          title: config.NOTIFICATION_TITLE, // (optional)
          message: notificationBody, // (required)
          playSound: true, // (optional) default: true
          soundName: 'default',
          number: notificationNumber,
          id: notificationNumber.toString()
        })

        dataStorageService.insertIntoNotificationsIndex([data[0].id])
        BackgroundFetch.finish(taskId)
      })
    })
  })
}
```

I made iOS setup following this instructions: https://github.com/transistorsoft/react-native-background-fetch/blob/HEAD/docs/INSTALL-AUTO-IOS.md

Why Background Fetch doesn't trigger periodically on iOS like on Android does?

Comment: Good news :)
Finally, it works. Notifications appeared on iPhone after two days. iOS background fetch algorithm is wired. It means when Simulate Background Fetch works in Xcode, it should be trigger automatically after some time. We can set only minimal frequency - 15 min. What is a maximal frequency? That's iOS mystery.

Comment: Im confused how this is good news.  Will this affect every user that uses your app?  Will they all have to wait for days for the notifications to begin?
Also....once they begin.....are they not guaranteed to happen every 15 mins?